# .removeClass and .addClass in IE9 with IE7 mode acts weird

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet, which removes and adds classes. It works for ALL browsers, but if you on IE9 and set IE7 mode, an image (checkimage) starts to blink or disappear on add/remove classes action.. Here is a snippet:

```
_clearAndSetPrimary: function (row) {

    $j('#leademails tr.wasprimary').removeClass('wasprimary');

    $j('#leademails tr.isprimary').removeClass('isprimary').addClass('wasprimary');
    $j('#leademails tr.wasprimary td.primary').html('<a title="make this the login email" href="#makeprimary">make primary</a>');

    row.addClass('isprimary');
    $j('#leademails tr.isprimary td.primary').html(checkimage)

}
```

UPDATE:  That was IE9 RC version bug. Installed stable IE9 and the issue fixed itself..

Comment: Why would you set IE7 mode? That's for making sites that are written for IE7 work in IE9, not for checking if a site works in IE7.

Comment: Because some users have that mode checked on IE9.

Comment: That mode is per site. Why would anyone turn it on for a site that is working?

Comment: It's not per site. Once you change IE9 to display document mode as IE7, it will stay for all sites, even you close and reopen a browser. Why would they want to do that? ask visitors.. we get plenty users with such settings.

Comment: Is this a widespread problem? This is the first time I hear that people actually use the IE7 mode let alone leave it on if it's not per site (which NB is a terrible UI choice by Microsoft).

Comment: We ran into a problem where a lot of our QA teams browsers were defaulting to IE7 document mode with IE9 browser mode. This has to do with some automatic compatibility mode settings for accessing sites on an intranet. It's under the tools menu (which is only on the menu bar which is hidden by default), compatibility mode settings.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what to say - another question I read yesterday reported something similar with the way IE acts when you use add/remove/toggleClass. Have you tried plain old `.setAttribute()`/`.attr()`?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely true. After doing the remove, I had to check the class name and add extra classes if they had been removed.

Javascript also properly blows up using $('#nodeID').position() - no fail gracefully, no messaging, null or undefined, just function die, so I had to try catch it. Nice to know that if for some really random reason you must support IE7 mode in IE 9 then jQuery will 'freak out'.